# How to accept Ngrok connections on Docker Django

Tags: django, docker, ngrok

I'm trying to create tunnel connection and accept Stripe payment success requests.

docker-compose.yml:

```
...
django:
  ...
  
  ports:
    - '8000:8000'
ngrok:
  container_name: ecommerce_ngrok_ctnr
  image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
  restart: unless-stopped
  command: start --all --config /etc/ngrok.yml
  ports:
    - 4040:4040
  depends_on:
    - django
  volumes:
    - ./ngrok/ngrok.yml:/etc/ngrok.yml
```

ngrok.yml:

```
version: 2
authtoken: ***
tunnels:
  django:
    proto: http
    addr: localhost:8000
    inspect: true
```

The error code is:

```
ERR_NGROK_8012
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused
```